# Measurement error in dependent variable?

Tags: least-squares, measurement-error

Suppose the cross-sectional model that I wish to estimate via OLS is $Y_{i} = a + b X_{i} + e_{i}$. Say that $Y_i$, $X_i$ and $e_i$ are normally distributed with mean 0 and constant variance. This specification adheres to all Gauss-Markov assumptions.

But we don't observe $Y_i$. We instead observe $\hat{Y}_i = Y_i - \nu_i$. So I estimate $\hat{Y}_{i} = a + b X_{i} + e_{i}$, or equivalently $Y_i =a+bX_i+(e_i+\nu_i)$, or equivalently $Y_i=a+bX_i+\epsilon_i$, $\epsilon_i = e_i + \nu_i$. What happens in the following two cases:

***1)*** $\nu_i \sim N(q,\sigma_\nu)$, where $q$ is some positive constant.

***2)*** $\nu_i$ has mean 0 and variance $\sigma_\nu \forall i$ but is skewed (say, positively).

***3)*** $\nu_i \sim N(q_i,\sigma_\nu)$, where $q$ is a random variable whose value is conditional upon observation $i$.

My inclination for 1) is that the $\hat{a} = a - q$. Not sure of 2) or 3) (preliminary ideas only).

When I ask "what happens", I'm asking about (i) bias/consistency/efficiency of coefficient estimates (ii) accuracy of coefficient standard errors (iii) anything else.

Undeveloped comments/suggestions are welcome as well!

Comment: Is $e_t$ an error term? If so, why not redefine it as $e_t-\nu_t$?

Comment: Yeah $Y_i = a + bX_i + (e_i + \nu_i)$, but not sure how to then solve my problems.

Comment: It seems more natural to use a single error term, but if you have to separate error sources it can make sense to have two. :) In (1) you do indeed get $E\hat{a}=a+q$ if $\hat{a}$ is the usual OLS estimator, so $\hat{a}_{corrected}=\hat{a}-q$ seems reasonable if $q$ is known. In (2) you still have unbiased consistent estimators, but OLS is not necessarily very efficient. Do you mean $X_i$ when you say "observation $i$" in (3)?

Comment: I meant that $E[\nu_i]$ is conditional upon $i$ (i.e. it isn't constant over all $i$). So we **can't** write $E[\nu_i]=c$ where $c$ is some arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you have is an error term with a nonzero mean.  Consequently the assumptions required for OLS to be appropriate are violated.  So you should use OLS directly. However if q is known subtract it from the Y^$_i$s and apply OLS using the variance of the error term which is σ$^2$$_ν$+σ$^2$$_e$.

Given that this is a time series even after inclusion of the covariate X$_i$ there may still be some autocorrelation structure left in the series.  So it might be appropriate to also include some autoregressive and/or moving average terms.

Comment: *(1)* Do you mean that I shouldn't use OLS directly? (instead of "should"), *(2)* It's actually cross-sectional, I made a typo in my OP by subscripting with $t$, *(3)* What's the consequence if I do not know (i) what the value of the constant $q$ is, and (ii) what $q_i$ is, yet in both (i) and (ii) I just apply OLS over the equation $\hat{Y}_i = a + b X_i + e_i$ without any adjustments?

Comment: It wasn't the time index that made me think it was time series data, you stated that it was a time series.  If you do not know q i don't think there is a way to know how to adjust the Ys.  I am suggesting that if you know q and can subtract it that then the error term would have 0 mean and OLS can be applied but with the appropriate variance which is larger than teh variance of the e$_i$s

Comment: (+1) useful to know, but I'm more looking to understand the *consequences* of not controlling for the three types of measurement error while using OLS.

Comment: If you don't account for the bias the OLS estimates will be biased and inconsistent. I think it is clear that it is treating the residuals as though they have 0 mean and so it minimization of the sum of squared residuals is not appropriate.  If you take an incorrect approqach you will get wrong answers!

Comment: What do you say to the assertion that a constant measurement error (say $E\nu_i = 1 \forall i$) will ***only*** bias the intercept estimate. Slopes are still unbiased and consistent?

Comment: If that is the only error term then the data will fit perfectly to a line that has the intercept shifted by 1. If the measurement error is constant but the e term is still presented the fitted line is shifted by the constant 1 on the intercept. If nu has mean 1 and a positive variance and is distirbuted symmetrically around 1 the bias will stillonly be in the intercept and not the slope.

Comment: Alright, and with a non-constant $E\nu_i$ I'm guessing that the slope estimates will also be biased and inconsistent?